# Facebook FQL not returning some public events

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using FQL in PHP to automatically fetch all future (public) events created by any of the fan pages on a list. The process works flawlessly with most pages, however some pages do not return any events at all.

Here is the FQL used to obtain all events of a certain fan page. At the time I wrote this post it had one future event.

```
SELECT 
        eid, name, pic_cover, start_time, end_time, location, description, attending_count 
    FROM 
        event 
    WHERE 
        eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = xxxxx ) 
    AND 
        (start_time >= now() OR end_time >= now())
    ORDER BY 
        start_time ASC
```

You can test this query using Facebook's [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). The explorer allows you to execute the query via their application or any of your own. And it allows for use of either an application access token or a user access token.

So here is the (frustrating) bottom line:

- When the explorer executes this query via the default "Graph API Explorer"-application using a user access token, the event is found.
- When the explorer executes this query via any of my own applications using an application access token, the event is **not found**.
- When the explorer executes this query via any of my own applications using a user access token, the event **is** found.

I am very sure the the event in question is public. Also, I did not personally like the fan page or join the event. So I am at a loss as to why my user access token seems to have enough rights to access the event, but the application access token does not.

Do you have any idea? :)

NOTE: The same code functions perfectly with other fan pages. So trivial bugs like syntax errors aren't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, because you're querying User-specific data (with the subquery on the event_member table).

See the docs here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/#permissions

They're stating

> The **user_events** permission for non-public events **or to see all events
>   a user is attending**

If you use the Graph API Explorer, you as a User grant the app the permissions to access your data (User Access Token).

Also, I wonder if your FQL really does what you want: Would the uid in your subquery be the Page ID?

Comment: The uid would be the Page ID, yes. What I don't get is why this FQL works for most pages, but not the one mentioned in the initial post. They're all just (public) pages hosting (public) events.

Comment: When selecting using **creator = xxx** instead of using the event_member table, the same thing happens. For most pages it'll fetch all future public events, but for the mentioned page it will not. Unless I use a user access token.